# NGINX rewrite configuration for another website in a sub directory triggers script download

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

This is my original nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my-site.com;
    return       301 http://www.my-site.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.my-site.com;
    root         /var/www/sites/mysite/public_html;
    index        index.php index.html index.html;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/mysite.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/mysite.error.log;

    ssl off;

    location / {
        try_files    $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
        fastcgi_buffers  16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size  32k;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Then I want to add another site in subfolder lets say **"my-site.com/another_app"** but this site requires rewriting url like:

```
my-site.com/another_app/api
my-site.com/another_app/home
```

becomes

```
my-site.com/another-app/api.php
my-site.com/another-app/index.php?mod=home
```

i already tried to add rewrite inside the **"location /"** like this

```
location / {
    try_files    $uri $uri/ index.php;
    rewrite ^/another-app/api$ /another-app/api.php break;
    rewrite ^/another-app/([A-Za-z0-9-|_]+)/?$ /another-app/index.php?mod=$1 break;
}
```

But every time I try to access **"my-site.com/another-app/api"** it triggers to download the php script

Did I missing something?

Comment: Try using `last` instead of `break` (assuming that the two application share the same document root. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) for details.

Comment: I tried using last but still triggers script donwload

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I answer this way.

I have had this problem only with static files like css and js:

I fixed it with indexing the files in the static folder:

```
location /static/ {
    # My static files including the css reside inside my static
    # folder e.g. /static/css/style.css
    # autoindex on will index everything under the given location

    autoindex on;
 }
```

Also what @Richard Smith said, try using last.